# Child Theme Path Being Ignored With wp_enqueue_scripts

Tags: child-theme

I've created a child theme under `wp-content/themes/my-theme` with 5 files thus far:

```
|-my-theme
|----assets
|--------css
|------------bootstrap.min.css
|--------js
|------------bootstrap.min.js
|----functions.php
|----index.php
|----style.css
```

Now the problem is within my `functions.php` file, I've tried adding my `.css` and `.js` file like this:

```
<?php 
    # functions.php

    /**
     * add css | js files to WP
     */
    function theme_asset_setup()
    {
        # styles
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css', []);

        # scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', []);
    }

    /** actions **/
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_asset_setup');
```

This half does the job. This adds my `.js` and `.css` file with this path:

> http://site.local/wp-content/themes/twentynineteen/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=5.1

My parent theme is `twentynineteen` as specified in my `style.css` file:

```
/*
 Theme Name: My Theme
 Author: treybake
 Description: foobar
 Requires at Least: WordPress 4.9.6
 Version: 0.1
 License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
 Text Domain: my-theme
 Template: twentynineteen
 */
```

So I'm guessing this has some sort of factor on why my `.css` and `.js` - but I'm not sure how to debug further.

Why is my child theme path being ignored for my css/js files?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_template_directory_uri()` is explicitly for getting the URL to the parent theme, which is why your scripts and styles are being enqueued at that path (in this context the "template" is the parent theme).

The equivalent function for getting the child theme path is `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`. If you don't have a child theme then both these functions do the same thing, but when you are using a child theme the choice is important.

However, both these functions have been superseded by much more useful functions: [`get_theme_file_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_file_uri/) and [`get_parent_theme_file_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_parent_theme_file_uri/).

`get_theme_file_uri()` will get the URL to a specific file in your theme. If your theme is a child theme it will look for the file there, but if it can't find it, it will look in the parent theme. `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` can't do this.

So for your use case, you should use `get_theme_file_uri()`:

```
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_theme_file_uri( 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' ), [] );
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_theme_file_uri( 'assets/js/bootstrap.min.js' ), [] );
```

The main difference in usage is that rather than concatenating the rest of the file path to the end, you pass it as an argument. This is why it's able to check the parent theme for the file.

Comment: ah I see! Seems a bit backwards to not get applied theme stylesheet directory rather than get parent theme uri .. but hey ho!! will accept in 5 mins

Answer (score 1):

Because this is a child theme, you should use

```
 # styles
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css', []);

        # scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', []);
```

`get_template_directory_uri()`
pulls from the parent theme directory

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`
pulls from the child theme directory